# Requirejs ScriptError in IE11

Tags: requirejs, internet-explorer-11

It seems like the IE11 keeps executing JavaScript after load abort by user. I have a valid and working requireJS configuration with lots of modules.

When I open my Site and press the abort button (or click on the logout button) IE11 aborts all requireJS related async requests but keeps executing the requireJS Code (I figured it out with Debug and Network Panel). That shows an error like:

```
{description: "Script erro...", 
 message: "Script erro...", 
 name: "Error", 
 originalError: Event {...}, 
 requireModules: Array[1], 
 requireType: "scripterror"}
```

(Because the async request for main.js was aborted)

All other browsers seem to stop JS execution if the user aborts loading the page (which is the right behaviour). Is there a way to handle that behaviour with requireJS?